# How to get the width of an element using ref in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get the width of an element, and to do this I'm using the following...

```
export default () => {
    const { sidebarOpen } = useContext(AuthContext)
    const containerRef = useRef()

    const getWidth = () => myRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().width

    const [width, setWidth] = useState(0)

    console.log(sidebarOpen)

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleResize = () => setWidth(getWidth())

        if(myRef.current) setWidth(getWidth())

        window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize)
        console.log('abc', myRef.current.offsetWidth)

        return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize)
    }, [myRef, sidebarOpen])

    console.log(width)

    return (
        <div ref={containerRef}>
            ...
        </div>
    )
}
```

When the width of the screen is changed in dev tools page resize, it works fine, but when the value of sidebar changes from 'true' to 'false' (or vice-versa). It returns the previous value of the container width. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, I need to get the most up to date value of the container width every time it changes, whether this is caused by a change to 'sidebarOpen' or not.

Comment: You are currently measuring the width of the window not of the element (the div).
You should do containerRef.current.addEventListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a `div` element takes the full width of its parent.

I guess you're using flexbox for the sidebar, so when it closes, the element that contains the content (not the sidebar) expands to the full width of the available space.

This might be the issue that you're facing.

The `div` with flexbox (on the left we have the `Sidebar` component and on the right the content):

[image: Div with sidebar]

And right now, when there is no Sidebar:

[image: No sidebar]

As another example, let's create a `div` that has no other property rather than `backgroundColor`:

Eg:

```
<div style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>Hello</div>
```

And the result:
[image]